# When is a move operation performed on a function argument c++

Tags: c++, move-semantics, order-of-execution

Taking as example

```
void f(B b, A&& a) {...}
B g(B b, A a) {...}

int main() {
    B b;
    A a;
    f(g(b, a), std::move(a));
}
```

I presume this would be valid code seeing as an `std::move()` is merely a `static_cast` and from what I gather all function parameters are evaluated first (with no order guarantee) before copied / moved (which I assume is part of the function call not parameter evaluation) to the function's context.

Comment: This has nothing to with [tag:operator-precedence].

Comment: @user207421 Unfortunately the `operator-precedence` tag on SO is really messed up. It has a bad definition and is aliased to `evaluation-order`, which is what's really relevant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is valid.

As you have said, `std::move` is just a `static_cast` to *rvalue* (`&&`).

The expression:

```
f(g(b, a), std::move(a));
```

does not lead to an *undefined behavior* even if the arguments evaluation order is not guaranteed.

Indeed, the evaluation of the second argument `std::move(a)` does not affect the evaluation of the first one.

The "*move operation*" (here intended as the operation of "stealing" the resources held by the argument) is something can happen in the body of `f` (when all arguments are already evaluated).